# Executing output dynamically on different commands in terminal or in unix

Tags: bash, unix, alias

I've sub folders named 1 to 1000 under some path, lets say /path/to/mydir. So I want to create custom alias so some approach such that when I enter 105 then it should take me to /path/to/mydir/105. behind the screen i need to execute 
`cd /path/to/mydir/105` command.

what changes should i need to do on .bashrc to do this?

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ((i=1;i<=1000;i+=1)); do alias "$i=cd \"/path/to/mydir/$i\""; done
```

EDIT following comment on other anwser, `find` not needed to retrieve directories at first level: using glob expansion

```
for d in /path/to/mydir/*/; do
    dn=${d%/}                      # remove trailing /
    alias "${dn##*/}=cd \"$d\""    # remove path prefix from directory for alias name
done
```

Comment: LOL... that should be the solution

Comment: Just don't type `alias` alone on a slow terminal.

Answer (score 3):

I think if you don't use alias you could just make a simple script to do that

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/yourdir/${1}
```

and name that with `go` and put in your `$PATH` I recommend you to put it in the `/usr/local/bin/` path cause that's a path that user should have write privilege and put their executable binaries/scripts in.

so you could just

```
$go 105
```

to change your dir to the dir you want.

### EDIT

in fact you could also do that with alias according to [tldp](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html)

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases
alias go='cd  /path/to/your/dir/${1}'
```

and with this

```
source ./testalias.sh
go 1234
```

But you still needed to type a command `go` for this

Comment: and... adding the script's location to the $PATH or placing it/a symlink in `/usr/bin`

Comment: Ok got it.
I thought other option instead of creating a separate command i thought of adding logic in .bashrc file.

is there any way to identify if there is a number entered go to this dir?

something like,
`if ( $_ eq numeric)
       cd /path/to/yourdir/$_`
Could you please let me know is there any such logic I can write in .bashrc?

Comment: As far as I know, alias didn't have a backquote or replacement placeholder thing to achieve this... here is the [tldp](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) of alias

Comment: didn't think to make something generic, otherwise a function could be used instead `go() { cd "/path/to/mydir/$1";}`

Comment: @tuxian check the edit, in that way you could save the effect of creating a script and do the logic all in `.bashrc` , but still, you have to type another command to make that happen

Comment: @armnotstrong I got it, Thank you very much for everyone. I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

Use find and parse the output through awk, constructing an alias command that can be stored in a file srcfile

```
find /path/to/mydir -type d | awk -F\/ '{ print "alias "$NF"=\"cd \\\""$0"\\\"\"" }' > srcfile
```

Then in the bash.rc file:

```
source srcfile
```

This will load the aliases into your bash shell.

Comment: the alias will be defined for sh process only not calling shell

Comment: If I try the option which is suggested by @nahuel-fouilleul, all the folders from 1 to 1000 will be aliased whether the folders exists or not.\n

But using this method, I can able to create alias only for the folders exists in the given directory.  But only problem I face here is how can I add (') in the output.

Ex:
instead of 
alias 11939=cd home/username/path/to/dir/11939

I need the below line as output.
alias 11939='cd home/username/path/to/dir/11939'

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I need " before cd something like,
    find /path/to/mydir -type d | awk -F\/ '{ print "alias "$NF" = \""cd "$0"\"" }' | sh

But it is not working. any suggestions?

Comment: I have amended the solution for it to work better with the local shell and bash.rc.